# We have Solaris 10 VM in KVM (ProxmoxVE) how to check if Solaris is using all cores?

Tags: virtualization, solaris, kvm-virtualization, central-processing-unit

I'm trying to figure out is `VM Solaris 10` (which is virtualized with `KVM` on `ProxmoxVE`) using all allocated `CPUs`?
Host HW is Dell poweredge r720.

And find a way how to check that for example `gzip` on large file is running in parallel?

[This](http://www.fearthepenguin.net/2009/10/14/finding-how-many-cpuscoresthreads-in-a-solaris-server/) and [this](https://blogs.oracle.com/mandalika/entry/solaris_show_me_the_cpu) script are reporting only one virtual cpu/core.

I'm pretty much `n00b` when it comes to Solaris, and I have some `linux` skills.

Here is the `kstat` and `prtdiag` output

```
bash-3.2#  kstat cpu_info
    module: cpu_info                        instance: 0
    name:   cpu_info0                       class:    misc
    brand                           Common KVM processor
    cache_id                        0
    chip_id                         0
    clock_MHz                       2000
    clog_id                         0
    core_id                         0
    cpu_type                        i386
    crtime                          873425.09462698
    current_clock_Hz                1999921533
    current_cstate                  0
    family                          15
    fpu_type                        i387 compatible
    implementation                  x86 (chipid 0x0 GenuineIntel family 15 model 6 step 1 clock 2000 MHz)
    model                           6
    ncore_per_chip                  6
    ncpu_per_chip                   6
    pg_id                           1
    pkg_core_id                     0
    snaptime                        1213950.591382
    state                           on-line
    state_begin                     1375968172
    stepping                        1
    supported_frequencies_Hz        1999921533
    supported_max_cstates           1
    vendor_id                       GenuineIntel


# bash
bash-3.2# /usr/platform/`uname -i`/sbin/prtdiag
System Configuration: Bochs Bochs
BIOS Configuration: Bochs Bochs 01/01/2011

==== Processor Sockets ====================================

Version                          Location Tag
-------------------------------- --------------------------
other                            CPU 1
other                            CPU 2
other                            CPU 3
other                            CPU 4
other                            CPU 5
other                            CPU 6
```

Comment: What are the values of sockets and cores in /etc/qemu-server/NNN.conf (where NNN is the number of your Solaris VM)? How many cores have you allocated to the VM?

Comment: For SMP gzip, see `pigz`: http://zlib.net/pigz/

Comment: there is no config files for none of VMs in /etc/qemu-server/, but VM has alloceted 5 cores via WebGui.
@JannePikkarainen tnx for pigz.

Comment: I made a typo, there are allocated 6 cores via WebGUI.

Answer (score 0):

Additionally, You can use

```
psrinfo -pv
```

command to get number of physical processors/CPUs installed in your system.

Regarding CPUs utilization, run the gzip as you wish and then

```
mpstat
```

which will show you usage over all CPUs. By default, the output is sorted by CPU number. You should be interested in last four columns. If gzip runs in parallel on multiple CPUs you should see higher numbers in **"usr"** column for each CPU (time spent executing user code). If there is only one value higher and the other ones are around zero then it may mean that gzip is running on single CPU only.

Please keep in mind that this procedure assumes there aren't other CPU hog processes running on the system.

Comment: `bash-3.2# psrinfo -pv
The physical processor has 1 virtual processor (0)
  x86 (chipid 0x0 GenuineIntel family 15 model 6 step 1 clock 2000 MHz)

        Common KVM processor
`

And `mpstat` is showing only "usr" value around 90, same with `top` when I'm running gzip. I have also tried to change processor type in proxmoxVE from kvm64(defautl) to host which is xenon (sandy bridge) but then solaris wont boot.

Comment: So you have only one CPU in the system available.